# What is the use of "+" sign after square brackets in the following code?

Tags: java, string, split

```
ArrayList<String> text = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(s.split("[ !,?._'@]+")));
```

Can anyone explain what this '+' sign after the square brackets in the split method used for?

Comment: It matches the expression from once to infinite, you can play with it here. https://regexr.com/61lug

Comment: `split` is using *regular expressions* (regex) where `+` represents "one or more repetitions*. For more info see https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html

Answer (score 1):

In regular expressions, `+` means "one or more". In your case, the `split` method will slice your string when it finds one or more occurences of the symbols inside the square brackets.

Answer (score 1):

it is means "One or more" symbols.
Example:

```
const str = '100dfsdfds00';
str.match(/[a-z]/g) // [d, f, s...]
```

```
str.match(/[a-z]+/g) // [fsdfds]
```

Comment: While the answer part is correct, the example won’t compile and is a very strange choice to highlight what `+` does in refer.